# Core Data returns null for columns

Tags: core-data

Core Data returns null for column name.

It's my code in viewcontroller

```
for (TaskyEntity *task in [mycoredata searchAllData]) {
    NSLog(@"title: %@",task.title);
    NSLog(@"i:%i ",i);
    i++;
}
```

and it's output:

```
2013-03-17 19:31:08.462 tasky[2623:c07] title: (null)
2013-03-17 19:31:08.463 tasky[2623:c07] i:1
2013-03-17 19:31:08.464 tasky[2623:c07] title: (null)
2013-03-17 19:31:08.464 tasky[2623:c07] i:2
2013-03-17 19:31:08.465 tasky[2623:c07] title: (null)
2013-03-17 19:31:08.466 tasky[2623:c07] i:3
```

TaskEntity class:

```
-(NSArray *)searchAllData {
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    [request setEntity:entitydescription];
    NSError * error=nil;
    NSArray *matchData = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    return matchData;
}
```

Comment: This is not related to Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Since the loop ran three times, the fetch must have returned three objects. Based on your code, the `title` attribute **is** null, and that's why you're getting that result. It's not clear where (or if) you're trying to set this attribute, but your results indicate that it's unset.